# Is it possible to make SVG text animations infinite?

Tags: html, svg

I have made the transparent text appear and disappear within 3 seconds, and I want to click the SVG to make the disappeared text appear again and again, is it poosible to make it?
Thanks for any help and creative thougths

```
<svg>
        <text x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue" opacity="0">&#8203;Hello
        <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="click" dur="0.3s" from="0" to="1" restart="never" fill="freeze"></animate>
        <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="click+3" dur="0.3s" from="1" to="0" restart="never" fill="freeze">
        </animate>
        </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 2 animations

For the begin use a list of values separated with semicolons: `begin="theSVG.click;theSVG.click+3"`

Use `repeatCount="indefinite"` for an infinite animation.

Instead of using the from and to attributes you can use a values attribute `values="0;1;0"` where the values are separates by semicolons.

Also the user can't know where the text is so clicking the text may be a problem. Instead you cah give the svg element an id (theSVG - in this case) and use this id to start the animation when the user is clicking the svg element `begin="theSVG.click;theSVG.click+3"`

You can use any other visible svg element for this.

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg id="theSVG">
            <text x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue" opacity="0">&#8203;Hello
            <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="theSVG.click;theSVG.click+3" dur="0.3s" values="0;1;0" restart="never" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
            
            </text>
    </svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> I am tring to make the "HELLO" re-clickable after it disappear after 3s, what should I do?

In this case you need to delete `restart="never"`

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg id="theSVG">
            <text x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue" opacity="0">&#8203;Hello
            <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="theSVG.click" dur="3s" values="0;1;0"  repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"></animate> 
            </text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: This is the specification for SMIL animations: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html

Comment: Madam/ Sir, I tried this code, and found out that this is mean to make "HELLO" flashing, but I am tring to make the "HELLO" re-clickable after it disappear after 3s, what should I do?

Comment: Thanks for you reference, I am going to absorb it, but I dont think there is a option of "repeatcount" could help me get what I want as I comment just now

Comment: Thank you Madam/Sir please check my new answer